# How to get the links (href) of several matches using python Selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, scrape

If you visit this site,

https://www.premierleague.com/results

You will be able to see several match results. If you click on each match, you will be directed to another website.

My question is how can I get the href (link) of each match.

```
links = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="mainContent"]/div[3]/div[1]')
for link in links:
    x = link.get_attribute("href")
    List.append(x)
```

This is what I have so far and it is not working.

Comment: don't use `[3]` and `[1]` because this selects only one element. You have to write better XPATH

Comment: I see elements like `<div data-href="//www.premierleague.com/match/66686" ...>` and maybe you should search `//div[@data-href]` and later get `get_attribute("data-href")`

Answer (score 1):

I see elements like

```
<div data-href="//www.premierleague.com/match/66686" ...>
```

and you could search

```
//div[@data-href]
```

and later use `get_attribute("data-href")`

---

Full working code

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
#from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from webdriver_manager.firefox import GeckoDriverManager
#import time

url = 'https://www.premierleague.com/results'

#driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=ChromeDriverManager().install())
driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=GeckoDriverManager().install())

driver.get(url)

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

#time.sleep(5)

# close popup window with "Accept All Cookies"
button = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//button[text()="Accept All Cookies"]')))
button.click()

all_items = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//div[@data-href]')
print('len(all_items):', len(all_items))
for item in all_items:
    print(item.get_attribute('data-href'))
```

Result:

```
len(all_items): 40

//www.premierleague.com/match/66686
//www.premierleague.com/match/66682
//www.premierleague.com/match/66687
//www.premierleague.com/match/66689
//www.premierleague.com/match/66691
//www.premierleague.com/match/66684
//www.premierleague.com/match/66705
//www.premierleague.com/match/66677
//www.premierleague.com/match/66674
//www.premierleague.com/match/66675
//www.premierleague.com/match/66676
//www.premierleague.com/match/66679
//www.premierleague.com/match/66672
//www.premierleague.com/match/66678
//www.premierleague.com/match/66680
//www.premierleague.com/match/66681
//www.premierleague.com/match/66673
//www.premierleague.com/match/66633
//www.premierleague.com/match/66584
//www.premierleague.com/match/66513
//www.premierleague.com/match/66637
//www.premierleague.com/match/66636
//www.premierleague.com/match/66635
//www.premierleague.com/match/66666
//www.premierleague.com/match/66670
//www.premierleague.com/match/66668
//www.premierleague.com/match/66665
//www.premierleague.com/match/66667
//www.premierleague.com/match/66669
//www.premierleague.com/match/66654
//www.premierleague.com/match/66656
//www.premierleague.com/match/66659
//www.premierleague.com/match/66657
//www.premierleague.com/match/66655
//www.premierleague.com/match/66652
//www.premierleague.com/match/66660
//www.premierleague.com/match/66661
//www.premierleague.com/match/66653
//www.premierleague.com/match/66658
//www.premierleague.com/match/66524
```